# Loop over all spans and update one failed whit JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few spans in my html code and I will update one of them. So I have give every span an unique number in the attribute `data-id` of that span. The span has also a class whit the name `votes`.

The problem is now if I loop over all the spans, I check if the `data-id` of the element is equal to the id I receive from the server by SignalR method.

Here is some html:

```
<span data-id="7" class="votes">3</span>
<span data-id="9" class="votes">-1</span>
```

This code below doesn't update the span I will update.

```
var voteSpans = $(".votes");
var number = voteSpans.length;

for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    if (voteSpans[i].dataset.id == receivedId) {

        var oldVotes= parseInt(voteSpans[i].html());
        voteSpans[i].html(oldVotes+ parseInt(newVotes));
    }
}
```

But this code goes update all the spans whit the class `votes`:

```
var voteSpans = $(".votes");
var number = voteSpans.length;

for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    if (voteSpans[i].dataset.id == receivedId) {

        var oldVotes= parseInt(voteSpans[i].html());
        voteSpans.html(oldVotes+ parseInt(newVotes));
    }
}
```

See the different between the code on last line.

How comes this?

Comment: not seeing it I just saw voteSpans[i].dataset.id   while in jquery its .attr('data-id')  or .data('id')

Comment: You have asked a very good question. It describes the scenario clearly and helps the readers to understand the problem instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using the bracket notation for getting the element. A jQuery object is an array-like object. If you use the bracket notation the value at the specified index is returned.

The returned value is a DOM element that doesn't have `html` method. Use the `eq` method instead which gets an element by index, but the returned value is a jQuery-wrapped object:

```
voteSpans.eq(i).html(oldVotes+ parseInt(newVotes));
```

Also note that `dataset` property is not widely supported.  Consider using the jQuery `.data()` method instead. Here is an example using jQuery methods:

```
$(".votes").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('id') === receivedId;
}).text(function(_, oldVotes) {
    return +oldVotes + parseInt(newVotes, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered why you just use `.each()` to loop through all spans with `.votes` class and use `.text()` for span no need to use `.html()` while spans in your case doesn't have html.

```
$('.votes').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-id') == receivedId){ //you can use $(this).data('id');
       var oldVotes= parseInt($(this).text());
       $(this).text(oldVotes + parseInt(newVotes));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do note that you don't have to loop through all of them to compare. You can access it directly with:

```
var voteSpan = $(".votes[data-id="+receivedId+"]");
```